# How do I count in a Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, count, mode

```
import pandas as pd

# Read CSV data file:
df = pd.read_csv('~/nclab-data-read/titanic.csv')

# Port where most passengers embarked:
port = df['Embarked'].mode()[0]
**# Count these passengers:
n_port = df[['Name']].loc[df['Embarked'] == 1].count()[0]**
```

I believe I have something incorrect in the bottom row, but can't figure out what.

Comment: `sum(df['Embarked'] == port)` is probably enough for what you want.

Comment: To improve this and future questions please include a small subset of your data as a __copyable__ piece of code that can be used for testing as well as your expected output. See  [MRE - Minimal, Reproducible, Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20109391/15497888).

Comment: Geesh, so simple. Thank you very much!

Comment: Series.value_counts works well here, df['embarked'].value_counts().head(1)

Answer (score 0):

count() returns the number of non-null values. If applied to a DataFrame, it returns an array with 1 value per column (hence you need to take the index 0).

When applied to a Series, you get the number directly.

```
n_port = df.loc[df['Embarked'] == 1, 'Name'].count()
```

Obviously, both lines will return the same result.